# Java can't connect to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I want to connect a server to a mysql database.I included the driver library  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.I installed the mysql connector.I have this code:

```
    public void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

       String source="jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/security";
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(source,"root","");
```

}
I use xampp for the mysql database.I made a database called security.When i try to execute the connect() method I receive the

```
     No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/security
```

exception.I searched for hours but I could not find a solution to my problem.This is the entire code I used to try to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing "derby" with "mysql".

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
String source="jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/security";
```

to

```
String source="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/security";
```